# How to alter multiple text files using a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to alter multiple text files using a python scrip but I'm getting, not all, but some empty files as output. How to solve this?

```
def tratador_arquivo(arquivo):
with open(arquivo, 'r+',encoding="utf8") as inputtext:
    for ponto in inputtext:
        saida="saida_"+arquivo
        with open(saida, 'w') as saidatemp:
              saidatemp.write(ponto.replace('. ','.\n'))

import os

pasta = os.listdir('/Users/gabri/Desktop/Textos Imóveis')
os.chdir('/Users/gabri/Desktop/Textos Imóveis')

for arquivo in pasta:
    tratador_arquivo(arquivo)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you get and what you expect? It is not very clear by just looking at your code

Comment: As a side note: don't open things in `r+` mode if you don't want to write to them; just open them in `r` mode.

Comment: Also, if you're using a new-enough Python where UTF-8 is the default, you shouldn't pass `encoding="utf8"`, just leave the default—conversely, if you have to work with older Python versions where you need to specify UTF-8 on the input file, you also need to specify it on the output file, like `open(saida, 'w', encoding="utf8")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding abarnert's answer, you may get the whole code as follows:

```
def tratador_arquivo(arquivo):
    saida = "saida_" + arquivo
    with open(arquivo, 'r+',encoding="utf8") as inputtext, open(saida, 'w') as saidatemp:
        for ponto in inputtext:
            saidatemp.write(ponto.replace('. ', '.\n'))
```

Also mind the indentation error of the function content in the code you provided.

Comment: @GabrielAgapioBrantdeAquino Please upvote the question if it was helpful, and feel free to mark as accepted either of them.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your loop:

```
for ponto in inputtext:
    saida="saida_"+arquivo
    with open(saida, 'w') as saidatemp:
          saidatemp.write(ponto.replace('. ','.\n'))
```

This re-opens the same file over and over, once for each line of the input file. Since you open it in `w` mode, that truncates the file, erasing whatever you'd previously written there, and replaces it with just the (transformed) newest line. So, at the end of the loop, your output file only has the (transformed) last line of the input file.

This is probably *always* wrong (although it's hard to say that for sure when I don't know what exactly you're trying to do). But in cases where the input file ends with a blank line, it will be especially obvious that it's wrong, because the only thing in the output file will be that blank line.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
saida="saida_"+arquivo
with open(saida, 'w') as saidatemp:
    for ponto in inputtext:
        saidatemp.write(ponto.replace('. ','.\n'))
```

In other words, just open the file *once*, and keep writing new lines to it.

Comment: It seems you got it just right. However, you can avoid nested `with`'s in this case and put it just in a line of code, as I showed in my expansion to your answer.